# Direct IP Printing Library

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, printing

I have looked everywhere and cannot find the preferred way to print directly to an IP in C#. I am currently using the approach of opening up a socket and directly sending printer language to the port, which is working correctly with the exception of a couple brands of printers. I can print to these printers when installed on windows, but I am having issues with directly printing to them. I have seen several printing libraries for C#/.NET, but I have not seen any that mention printing to an IP. Does anyone know of one that will support this or have some alternative solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of network (any I would say) printer needs a driver to make it work, that's why you can print thru Windows and not directly to the printer. You need to get the printer's programmer reference manual and see how to send commands directly to the printer. I think all of these you already know, but it should be mention just in case.

You have a good explanation how to print directly to a printer in .NET C# [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091)

Although, it's not thru a socket but it's an alternative.
Good luck.